# create a new column in R using a user defined function

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I am trying to do pattern matching of a column and make a new column with a part of the matched pattern using a user-defined function.

Table name is data , it contains

```
MatchedColumn
24 abcd
32 gcef
45 lmno
```

Code is

```
f4<-function()
{
  data$NewColumn <- gsub('([0-9]{2}) *','\\1',data$MatchedColumn)
}
```

and i am calling the function as f4(), but it is not executing the inside part of the function.

But when i run the below line alone its creating a new column after matching and the produced table is as shown.

```
data$NewColumn <- gsub('([0-9]{2}) *','\\1',data$MatchedColumn)
```

data:

```
MatchedColumn  NewColumn
 24 abcd         24
 32 gcef         32
 45 lmno         45
```

I am trying to use user defined function because i want to pass **NewColumn** and **MatchedColumn** name through function, something like this f4(NewColumn,MatchedColumn)

Please help if anyone knows how to do it!

Comment: give an argument to function, preferably `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

- You can pass data as argument to function

  ```
  f4<-function(data, col1, col2)
  {
     data[,col1] <- sapply(data[col2], function(x)gsub("[^0-9]", "", x))
     return(data)
  }

  newdata <- f4(data, 'NewColumn', 'MatchedColumn')
  str(newdata)
  ```
- You can make the assignment globaly using `<<-`

  ```
  f4<-function(col1, col2)
  {
    data[col1] <<- sapply(data[col2], function(x)gsub("[^0-9]", "", x))
  }

  f4('NewColumn', 'MatchedColumn')
  ```

I would definitely prefer first option

Comment: Thnx First method works fine, but in the second method passing NewColumn and MatchedColumn is not working, so how to do that ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to allow seting the names of the columns - still I think optio 1 is preferable, since you can not mess your global variables

Comment: Doint that what we are getting is 
     MatchedColumn  NewColumn
      24 abcd        c(24,32,45)
      32 gcef        c(24,32,45)
    45 lmno        c(24,32,45)